# Can't insert Cyrillic symbols into MySQL with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a web app which uses com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to connect to MySQL database.
Here are jdbcMySQL.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username=....
jdbc.password=....

my.cnf has these settings:

[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
default-character-set = utf8
skip-external-locking
```

I create database like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE tblname (
    `login` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

**And the problem is:** if I make

```
insert into tblname (login, description) VALUES ('qwe', 'йцукен');
```

then I have in my table

```
| qwe |  йцукен |
```

BUT, if I make:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO work_time (login, date_time) VALUES (?, ?);", 
    new PreparedStatementSetter() {
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
          ps.setString(1, "qwe");
          ps.setString(4, "йцукен");
       }
    }
);
```

I have in my table:

```
qwe | ??????
```

Comment: in url try useUnicode = true

Comment: What editor or IDE do you use to edit your Java source code? You need to set the Java source encoding correctly (in most cases, the best option here is also UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is a bit crazy w.r.t. encodings, try:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Furthermore there is one more possible error cause: check that the editor encoding is the same as the javac compiler encoding. If they differ you see something different than what is compiled.

You could try the u-escaped version to test that, or look in the project settings:

```
"\u0439\u0446\u0432\u043a\u0435\u043d"
```